# Automatically drawing polygon layers between two different layers

Tags: gis, polygon, qgis

So I have a two different vector layers, both are point layers. I would like to draw a polygon either between them or ideally so it covers both layers.

However, I would like it so the polygon covers all the point layers that are closest to the other point layers

For instance, there are about 100 ofthese and I would like to autogenerate the polygon around each so it covers the points [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woVN1.png)

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks,
Lucy